# Filtering in R without the dplyr package

Tags: r

Is there an alternate function for filtering data in R that works similar to `dplyr::filter()` but is part of the R Base Environment?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `subset` from `base R` with `subset` argument which takes a logical expression as `filter` in `dplyr`

```
subset(mtcars, subset = carb == 4)
```

-output

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

Comment: Thank you! for some reason I returned no observation when with the "subset =" when I removed it and left it as subset(data, cut == 'XX') it worked perfectly.  Truly appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @AnthonyColes may be you have defined some object with `subset`.  Not sure